# Seaborn lineplot unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am hoping to understand why the following Seaborn lineplot behaviour occurs.

Spikes are occurring through the time-series and additional data has been added to the left of the actual data.

How can I prevent this unexpected behaviour in Seaborn?

Regular plot of data:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

aussie_property[['Sydney(SYDD)']].plot();
```

[image]

Seaborn plot of data:

```
sns.lineplot(data=aussie_property, x='date', y='Sydney(SYDD)');
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the data? One thing that leaps out at me is that your seaborn plot uses the 'date' column for the X axis while the other plot does not.

Comment: The CSV data is from the following link: https://www.corelogic.com.au/research/back-series

I set the date to datetime using the following code: 
aussie_property['date'] = pd.to_datetime(aussie_property['Date'], errors='coerce')

There are no missing dates in the data (data includes weekends).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a seaborn problem but a question of ambiguous datetimes.

Convert `date` to a [datetime object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with the following code:

```
aussie_property['date'] = pd.to_datetime(aussie_property['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

and you get your expected plot with seaborn

[image]

Generally, it is advisable to provide the format during datetime conversions, e.g.,

```
aussie_property['date'] = pd.to_datetime(aussie_property['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

because, as we have seen here, dates like `10/12/2020` are ambiguous. Consequently, the parser first thought the data would be month/day/year and later noticed this cannot be the case, so changed to parsing your input as day/month/year, giving rise to these time-travelling spikes in your seaborn graph. Why you didn't see them in the pandas plot, you ask? Well, this is plotted against the index, so you don't notice this conversion problem in the pandas plot.
More information on the format codes can be found in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).