# Plots shows doesn't show proper line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot stock data and its show weird line chart instead of continuous line. I am unable to understand what i am doing wrong. Please can anyone help me on this issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\dipes\Desktop\Data.csv')
df = df.set_index('Date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
#print(df)
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Close Price History')
df['Close'].sort_index().plot()
plt.xlabel('Date',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Close price',fontsize=18)
plt.autoscale(tight=True)
plt.show()
```

[Sample data in CSV format](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nkMC3i0rKd543VJpoAXClDw0CY02WwJJ?usp=sharing)

[image: Weird chart]

Comment: `df['Close'].sort_index().plot()` instead of `plt.plot(df['Close'])`?

Comment: Thanks, it did worked but trend line is still showing difference visuals like zig-zax lines

Comment: please help me on this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seaborn lineplot unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232680/seaborn-lineplot-unexpected-behaviour)

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, by default `pd.to_datetime` interprets the date strings in American format (i.e. `month-day-year`), but they're in `day-month-year`—the sensible format ;) . You have to tell Pandas to behave well:

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)
```

See the [docs on the `dayfirst` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Comment: We have the duplicate flag for a reason.